# Count and probability of two consecutive positives in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in a pivot table with numerical values like so
100
110
-100
-50
-37
0
201
131
122

How do I get a count of two (or three, or more) consecutive positive (or negative) values? In the example above such a count would yield 2 for positives (or one for negatives). Right now I have a way of calculating the longest streak, with an array formula, but I could not find a way of counting a specific streak of positives.

On a related note, if I have a value of 65% positives, how would I calculate the theoretical probability of having two, three or more consecutive positives?

Comment: Is zero meant to be positive?

Comment: No, for this purpose zero is neither.

Answer (score 1):

The following is in the assumption `0` is ***not*** positive. And for the example I've put your sample data in `A1:A9`.

---

Multiple options. Simplest might be:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$1:A$14>0,ROW(A$1:A$14)),IF(A$1:A$14<=0,ROW(A$1:A$14)))>1,1))
```

Entered as an array formula through CSE.